# Fixing a problem with `tabular'

Tags: tables

I facing problem with the following codes

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\frenchspacing
\sectionfont{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}

   \section*{Academic Qualifications}
   \begin{tabular}{rl}
   \textsc{Dec.2016-Now :}
    &PhD Student in ........., \textbf{Faculty of Sciences of ......}, 
     ......... spaces.\\
  & Ongoing thesis title: On extreme points of the joint numerical range of 
     commuting normal operators,.\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\   
   \textsc{October 2016 :}
  & Master Thesis in ........ at the \textbf{Faculty of Sciences of 
    ........}, ...........
   \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

After compilation I get

[image]

Comment: Yes the text is going out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `tabularx` with an `X` column.

I suggest to you also to get rid of the `:`s. At least don't leave a blank between the word and the `:`, in my opinion, it is ugly and, as far as I know, it is not used in English.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\frenchspacing
\sectionfont{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}

   \section*{Academic Qualifications}
   \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
   \textsc{Dec.2016-Now}
    &PhD Student in ........., \textbf{Faculty of Sciences of ......}, 
     ......... spaces.\\
  & Ongoing thesis title: On extreme points of the joint numerical range of 
     commuting normal operators,.\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\   
   \textsc{October 2016}
  & Master Thesis in ........ at the \textbf{Faculty of Sciences of 
    ........}, ...........
   \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

[image]